# Angular 2 Nested *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I am currently trying to pass some indexes to a function but the first parameter (ii) returns undefined.

```
<div *ngFor="let tab of screen.data.tabs; let index = i;">
    <div *ngIf="tab.active">
        <div *ngIf="tab.questions">
            <div *ngFor="let question of tab.questions; let index = ii;">
                <div class="scenarioContainerQUESTION">
                    <p [innerHtml]="question.text"></p>
                    <div *ngFor="let option of question.options; let iii = index;" class="option" [ngClass]="{'optionSelected': option.selected}">
                        <label [for]="ii+'_'+iii">{{option.text}}</label>
                        <input [id]="ii+'_'+iii" [name]="'group'+ii" type="radio" [value]="ii" (click)="optionClicked(ii,iii)" />
                    </div>
                    <button [ngClass]="{'fade': selectedOption == -1}" (click)="ManageSubmit()">SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you actually using ng2, or the latest - ng5?

Comment: Try `let i = index` and `let ii = index` (only `let iii = index` is OK).

Comment: @pixelbits I am using ng5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign index value to the variables not the otherway,

```
<div *ngFor="let tab of screen.data.tabs; let i= index;">
```

also

```
<div *ngFor="let question of tab.questions; let ii= index;">
```

Comment: i Knew it would be something tiny haha thanks everyone for the quick resonse.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf). The correct syntax for binding to `index`:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>
```